# Udacity python code a quiz

Tags: python, loops, project, infinite

I am currently doing Udacity's introduction to programming development course. As a part of this course, I have to create a fill in the blanks game. The game is structured like this:

The user is asked to choose a level based on difficulty. Once the user decides what level he/she wants to play, the parameters: *question, the answers to that question, blanks list, and an index of 0 are passed to the function* **Question Validation**.

At the **question validation** function. We assess whether user input matches what is contained in the answers based on the index. For example, if I am filling in the first blank, then my answer(input) must equal that of answers[0]. If it does not then the user has 4 tries to get it right. If the user does not, the game is quit. Once the user selects the right answer, this is passed to the function **traverse**.

Here is the code for question validation

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e5doud7wt2awlfo/AACoMdohawZj54RwjIWvtAKda?dl=0

The function **traverse** takes in as parameters:*the question; the list of answers to that question; and the index as parameters.* Based on this information, this function will fill in the question blanks accordingly and passes this back to the **question validation** for the user to then fill in the next blank. When all the blanks are filled, the program is stopped.

Here is the code for traverse

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4cra1hah5xww9q/traversefunct.py?dl=0

I have written comments in my code that further elaborate on what I have outlined here.

Here is the complete code

https://www.dropbox.com/s/npendg2ey63e8rr/codeaquiz.py?dl=0

The code seems to work fine and does what I want it to do up until filling the 4th blank. At this point if I choose the wrong answer and then go back and choose the right answer. It acknowledges that I have chosen the right answer but then prompts for the answer again. Its an infinite loop and I cant see for the life of why it is happening here when for filling in previous blanks it was not working.

Here is a screenshot of what is happening with regards to being prompted again:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8sk8r19gz4ued2/Screenshot%202018-04-27%2014.13.22.png?dl=0

I cant for the life of me see why:

Comment: Please include a [mcve] **in the question itself**. Questions should be self-contained; we shouldn't have to go off-site to figure out what your question is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest that you read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your own code. Debugging is one of the most important skills for you to learn as an aspiring programmer. Also take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve] for tips on improving your question here on SO.

Comment: You never `break` your while loop in the else statement.

Comment: [I downvoted because being unresponsive to comments is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As zipa pointed out, you never `break` your while loop in the else statement on line 146 unless you run out of `tries`. A one line "fix" is to simply put an `exit()` after line 98 within the `traverse()` function.

Comment: what could I do to improve the way I composed the question?

Comment: (Probably) try to follow the rules that the other users posted. In addition, present a question that is succinct and as limited in scope as possible. For instance, "I can't see for the life of me why [my program isn't functioning correctly]" is not a good question, if it even is a question. Unfortunately, although you did provide all the necessary info to come to a solution, the scope of the problem was too large; debug your program as far as you can, then ask the question about whatever remains that needs explaining. Also, rather than explaining the program here, comment it in your code! :)

Comment: If my response helped to solve your problem / answer your question, please select it as the Accepted Answer!